# How to get information about applications on WebSphere using AdminService?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have adminService

```
private com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminService adminService = AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService ();
```

With it, I can get different information about the server, but I can’t get information about installed applications (names, status, running or not, etc.), I think I need to use the invoke method, but based on the documentation it’s not clear how to do this:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminService.html

I did not find such examples on the Internet, please tell me who knows what about this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the J2EEApplication and Application MBeans to get information about installed applications.  These references should help:

[Using administrative programs (JMX): Existence of MBeans for stopped components](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cjmx_mult_appsrvr.html)

[WebSphere Application Server Public MBean Interfaces](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTJ_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/index.html)

Regards, DaveZ